# Delphi 10.2 - Исключение выполнение функции в отладчике (...was eliminated by linker

Tags: delphi, компоновщик

Пользуюсь Delphi 10.2 уже месяцев 5, но до этого не видел, чтоб при отладке обычной функции

```
DateOf(now);
```

Деббагер исключал ее выполнение, со словами:

> DateOf(now)   -  Function to be called, DateOf, was eliminated by
>   linker

Как включить обратно выполнение?

P.S.
- Delphi7 – в этом случае все отрабатывает
- и это не единственный такой момент...

Comment: отключить оптимизацию?

Comment: Project - Options - Compiling - Optimization = false - уже пробовал - **НЕ** помогает

Comment: Delphi 10 достаточно глюкавая ветка версий (ловил на ней и не такие абсурдные баги, а даже в строках типа `someArray[K+1]` ругалось и падало пока не выносил K+1 в отдельную переменную, при том что все было в правильных границах). Попробуйте обновиться до последнего апдейта. Среду кстати после изменения настроек перезапускали, и DCU своего проекта все чистили?

Comment: @Kromster, пользуюсь версией "Version 25.0.26309.314"   О **"изменении"** каких настроек вы говорите, и что подразумевается под **"чисткой DCU"**?

Comment: Имею ввиду: Зашли в настройки (Project - Options), поменяли Optimization или что-то еще, сохранили проект, закрыли проект и IDE, почистили в папке проекта все DCU файлы, запустили студию и проект, пересобрали Build.

Comment: Такое же поведение и в Xe5. Скорее всего это из-за того что функция объявлена как `inline`. Напишите свой аналог. И вызовете его где нибуть в программе

Comment: @Kromster . к сожалению это не помогает